# How to only output warnings when launching a program under gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have a program which i am trying to debug. When the program is started under gdb, there are several warnings being outout, but then those warnings are hidden under the output of the program.

How can one ensure that only warnings are shown and remain avalable to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to suppress output from your program, then the answer is to do it exactly as you'd do it in the shell.  gdb actually uses the shell to start the inferior when you type `run`, so some kinds of redirection work.

In this case, to suppress all output, you could do something like:

```
(gdb) run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm assuming here that the warnings are things gdb is printing that you want to see.  Unfortunately gdb doesn't remember what it has printed, so there's no way to ask it after the fact.